# i need to put back/ (change) WordPress Address (URL) - should be simple

Tags: wordpress

I made a mistake and changed the SETTINGS / WordPress Address (URL) in WordPress and now i cant get into the back-end anymore.

The problem is that, i have a site on a "dev" folder so the address was "mySite.com/dev", and this is where WordPress was(is). I mistakenly removed the "dev" and now its the normal "mySite.com".

I need to put everything back but since i removed the "/dev", WordPress always redirects me to the main site and i dont have access to the back end anymore.

How can i restore it so i can access my WordPress dev site on the dev folder?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this (especially if you aren't comfortable in phpMyAdmin) is to FTP in and edit your `wp-config.php` file in the base WP directory (e.g. mysite.com/dev) and add these lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.com/dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.com/dev');
```

Next time you visit the site it will automatically change the settings.  Note that this will cause the associated fields in the admin panel to be grayed out, so when you want to change the URL in the future you will need to either update or delete these lines from the wp-config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this settings via phpMyAdmin

in table `wp_options` change the option value for `siteurl` and `home`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different methods for resetting the site URL in WordPress. Some involve editing wp_options and others wp-config.php, with varying degrees of difficulty. See [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for recovery instructions.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the correct address, I got the best results by going into MYSQL directly and updating the entry.

I found that hard coding the site address by adding lines to wp_config.php gave incomplete results. The admin pages still looked buggy. And I couldn't change the address from the Wordpress admin site anymore. I'm sure phpMyAdmin works fine, but I didn't want to install anything extra.

1. Log in `$ mysql -u [your-mysql-user] -p`
2. Make a note of what your tables are named. I believe the "wp" prefix is standard for all table names, but this may vary by installation.

   ```
   > show databases;
   > use [your-wordpress-database];
   > show tables;
   > desc wp_options;
   ```
3. Look up current value.

   ```
   > SELECT option_id, option_name, option_value
   > FROM wp_options
   > WHERE option_name="siteurl";
   ```
4. Output should look something like: `1 | siteurl     | [current path with incorrect value]`
5. Replace with correct value

   ```
   > UPDATE wp_options
   > SET option_value="[new path]"
   > WHERE option_name="siteurl";
   ```